# selectRow on MUI Datatable

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable

This is my first try with [MUI Datatables](https://github.com/gregnb/mui-datatables) in React.
I want to get the data out of the Row I select on the Checkbox.

```
 const options = {
 
         download: false,
         print: false,
         viewColumns: false,
         filterTable: false,
         filter: false,
         onRowsSelect:(currentRowsSelected: any, allRowsSelected: any) => {console.log(allRowsSelected);}
 
     };
```

This gives me only the index of selected row. Is there a way to get the data of its row. I need the first cell of the row to delete/update with the database.
Can anybody help me
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the current API for `onRowsSelect` only provides the index of the row selected and the number of rows that are selected.

To retrieve row data, you would have to provide a `onRowClick` function. It listens to the `click` event on a row.

```
onRowClick: (rowData, rowState) => {
  console.log(rowData, rowState);
},
```

Answer (score 1):

You need use onRowClick even in options

```
const options = {
    filterType: 'dropdown',
    responsive: 'scrollFullHeight',
    serverSide: true,
    count: total,
    page: page,
    onRowClick: handleRowClick,
}
```

and pass this option into MUI DataTable

```
<MUIDataTable
   title={"Service Request List"}
   data={requests}
   columns={columns}
   options={options}
/>
```

Here is the row click handler:

```
const handleRowClick = (rowData, rowMeta) => {
    console.log(rowData, rowMeta);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get index of column selected from onRowsSelect function :

```
onRowsSelect : (curRowSelected, allRowsSelected) => {
    console.log("---RowSelect")
    console.log("Row Selected: ", curRowSelected);
    console.log("All Selected: ", allRowsSelected);
  }
```

and use this **index** for **get data from data list**